# SPFX : Sharepoint list column does not Exists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

> Error message: The property 'RequesterEmpID' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.XYZListItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

I edited some of the list column names in SharePoint. after which I get this error. 'RequesterEmpID' is one of the list column which was renamed.

Code:

```
  export function addDatatoSharepoint(props){ 
  return dispatch => {
    props.Web.lists.getByTitle('Listname').items.add({
      RequesterName: props.FirstName + " " + props.LastName,
      RequesterJobTitle: props.Title, 
      RequesterEmpID: props.EmpID, 
      RequesterDepartment: props.Department, 
      RequestDate: new Date().getDate(),
      DocumentID: props.DocumentID,  
    }).then(r => {
        console.log(r);
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the type of RequesterEmpID column?

Comment: Hi @Amos_MSFT, thank you for the quick response. The type of RequesterEmpID column is Single line of text.

Comment: As Ganesh saied,you need to check the internal name of RequesterEmpID column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding item to SharePoint list, we need to use the **internal name** of the column.

Check the internal name of your `RequesterEmpID` column using below link and use it in your code:

[Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Exactly the internal name is different. Thank you!!.